# SQLException: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMPORAL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to do inserts in batchupdate with jdbc template and I get the following error.
My application lives all the time and performs multiple inserts per hour as the events arrive.
I found a solution that generates a connection for every time I call the method and then close it, but it's not the right thing to do.
I need to use my generated connection through a bean only once.
any solution ?

my code:

```
private void insertarDatosEnDB(List<RowObject> dbObjectList) {

    try {

        String sql = "INSERT /*+ APPEND IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(" + table + "," + "NOKIA_JSON_RAW_PK " + ") */ INTO " + table +
                " (FECHA, NOMBRE_PROYECTO,NOMBRE_ARCHIVO, TIPO,  DOCUMENTO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    RowObject ci = dbObjectList.get(i);
                    ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(ci.getFecha().getTime()));
                    ps.setString(2, ci.getNombre_proyecto());
                    ps.setString(3, ci.getNombre_archivo());
                    ps.setString(4, "ALGUN-TIPO");
                    // Usando directamente un CLOB
                    Clob clob = ps.getConnection().createClob();
                    clob.setString(1, ci.getJson());
                    ps.setClob(5, clob);
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return dbObjectList.size();
                }
            });
            LOGGER.info("Se han insertado datos en la tabla con el nombre de archivo: {}", dbObjectList.get(0).getNombre_archivo());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String archivo = dbObjectList.get(0).getNombre_archivo();
           /*try {
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(".\\" + archivo + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt"), dbObjectList.get(0).getJson().toString());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            LOGGER.error("Error al insertar archivo {}  en DB Class: {}\n -Message: {}\n -Cause: {}\n -StackTrace: {}", archivo, e.getClass(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause(), e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void persistirDatosEnDB(List<RowObject> dbObjectList) {
    TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

    template.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            try {
                insertarDatosEnDB(dbObjectList);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                LOGGER.error("Error al insertar en DB Class: {}\n -Message: {}\n -Cause: {}\n -StackTrace: {}", e.getClass(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause(), e.getStackTrace());

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I guess this has nothing to do with your java code. Your tablespace cant be extended which could mean there is no space left on your hard drive e.g.

Comment: but this space is not released for each transaction? if I make a connection and close it is released for each batch ...@Meini

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your connection method. Temp space is used by some sorting and hashing processes (for example in joins and aggregation) and for temp tables. Typically ORA-01652 is caused by a poor execution plan (inefficient join order, access method etc) or by a large temp table. It's hard to tell whether it's one of those here, or something else. (By the way, I think you wanted the [`APPEND_VALUES`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-562DD503-2F99-448E-B044-737BE726B58A) hint, not `APPEND`.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, I got confused, append_values is the correct hint.

Comment: As @WilliamRobertson points out the APPEND hint is wrong for an INSERT with VALUES clause. However, it doesn't matter, because you're also using IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX, and that [disables APPEND mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-20390275-91A7-49DC-AAD1-A1FE943A4F75).